# selenium drag and drop Actions in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, draggable, drag

i'm trying to drag and drop some SVG element to another SVG element but those kind of code run without any error but not preform any task is any alternatives?

```
act.clickAndHold(drag).pause(2000)
        .moveToElement(drop)
        .release()
        .build().perform();
```

```
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
           .click(drag)
           .click(drop)
           .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
act.build();
act.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of these solutions can help you:

```
public void dragAndDrop(WebElement from, WebElement to) {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.dragAndDrop(from,to).perform();
    }
```

This is using JSExecutor:

```
public void dragAndDrop(WebElement from, WebElement to) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {\n" + "var event =document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");\n"
                        + "event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);\n" + "event.dataTransfer = {\n" + "data: {},\n"
                        + "setData: function (key, value) {\n" + "this.data[key] = value;\n" + "},\n"
                        + "getData: function (key) {\n" + "return this.data[key];\n" + "}\n" + "};\n" + "return event;\n"
                        + "}\n" + "\n" + "function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {\n"
                        + "if (transferData !== undefined) {\n" + "event.dataTransfer = transferData;\n" + "}\n"
                        + "if (element.dispatchEvent) {\n" + "element.dispatchEvent(event);\n"
                        + "} else if (element.fireEvent) {\n" + "element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);\n" + "}\n"
                        + "}\n" + "\n" + "function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {\n"
                        + "var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');\n" + "dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);\n"
                        + "var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');\n"
                        + "dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n"
                        + "var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');\n"
                        + "dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent,dropEvent.dataTransfer);\n" + "}\n" + "\n"
                        + "var source = arguments[0];\n" + "var destination = arguments[1];\n"
                        + "simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);", from, to);
    }
```

This another solution with Actions

```
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your_celector"));
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your_celector"));

int x = to.getLocation().x;
int y = to.getLocation().y;

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(from)
        .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .clickAndHold(from)
        .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .moveByOffset(x, y)
        .moveToElement(to)
        .moveByOffset(x,y)
        .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .release().build().perform();
```